# How to create a simple applet in my intranet?

Tags: java, applet

I have a libraries from open source for real time play click and sound. And i was working on it and it works in my desktop, then i wanted to test in browser 1  to browser 2.

This is compiled and it has a name like GameAudio.jar

Second example (using archieve) : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html

Can anyone kindly guide what i am doing wrong ? when i open run.html in firefox says "Start: applet not initialized"

```
My src directory:

.
├── audio
│   ├── MyGst.java
│   └── Test.java
├── models
│   ├── DigestAuthentication.java
│   ├── Global.java
│   ├── MainApplet_1.java
│   ├── MD5.java
│   ├── MessageDigest.java
│   ├── SIPProvider.java
│   └── SIPProviderListener.java
├── gameaudio
│   ├── MainApplet.java
│   └── README
└── video

My dist directory:

.
├── GameAudio.jar
├── lib
│   ├── sip-java-1.4.jar
│   └── jna-3.0.4.jar
├── README.TXT
└── run.html
```

cat run.html

```
<applet code=MainApplet width=600 height=600 archive="GameAudio.jar" ></applet>
~
~
~
```

Thanks

Comment: I hate applets.. Why not use flash or something?

Comment: @Shoban - yeah, cause *everyone* loves flash

Comment: @Shoba, FYI, do not underestimate anything. I love applets i hate flash, because i cant do 192 Khz transmission with that loveable Flash kit over Browser peer 2 peer. Where i can do in Applet using open source VLC frmeworks.

Comment: sorry guys.. just my personal opinion. no ofences meant to anyone.. Flash just cae out in the flow.I hate applets more than flash .. thats all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<applet code="MainApplet" width=600 height=600 archive="GameAudio.jar" ></applet>
```

Or this:

```
<applet code="gameaudio.MainApplet" width=600 height=600 archive="GameAudio.jar" ></applet>
```

Comment: You are the genius. You allowed me to build my SIP protocol and 3D audio over RTP ? :)